# Need small trim() adjustment in complex FormValidator function

Tags: php, function, validation, oop, methods

I've made the following function, but as it's gotten a bit complex I have no idea how to tackle the problem I have with it now.

Right now the function trims every input before it validates them.

I want it to check if the input `type` is `password` first so that it doesn't trim the input before the validation.

```
public function check($source, $inputs = array()) {
    foreach($inputs as $input => $requirements) {
        foreach($requirements as $requirement => $reqValue) {
            $input = escape($input);
            $inputValue = (isset($source[$input])) ? trim($source[$input]) : null;

            if($requirement === 'required' && (!isset($inputValue) || empty($inputValue))) {
                $this->addError($input, 'required');
                //var_dump($this->_errors);
            } elseif(!empty($inputValue)) {
                switch($requirement) {
                    case 'min':
                        if(strlen($inputValue) < $reqValue) {
                            $this->addError($input, $requirement);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'max':
                        if(strlen($inputValue) > $reqValue) {
                            $this->addError($input, $requirement);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'match':
                        if($inputValue != $source[$reqValue]) {
                            $this->addError($input, $requirement);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'unique':
                        $users = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM {$reqValue} WHERE {$input} = '{$inputValue}'");
                        if($users->count()) {
                            $this->addError($input, $requirement);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

I use it like:

```
$validate = new FormValidator();
$validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
    'password' => array(
        'type' => 'password', //<-- doesn't work yet in the function
        'required' => true,
        'min'      => 6
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your second foreach, check if `type` exists in $input. 
Store it in a temporary variable.

```
foreach($inputs as $input => $requirements) {
  $password = false;
  if (array_key_exists('type', $requirements) && $requirements['type'] == 'password') {
    $password = false;
  }
  foreach($requirements as $requirement => $reqValue) {
  [...]
```

... and then check it before you trim:

```
$inputValue = (isset($source[$input])) ? $source[$input] : null;
if(!$password) {
  $inputValue = trim($inputValue);
}
```